# How to draw curved div stacked on top of one another?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I am working on web application using Rect JS and I only have beginners knowledge in HTML and CSS.So can you please suggest me to achieve something like the following with a responsive UI that containing button,text and image.How can I write css styles to curve a div and place another one below it without any blank space.

[image: UI]

Can someone please suggest any solution? Any help would be really appreciated.I have tried radial-gradient method like following.

```
<div className="background1">
 ....
</div>
<div className="background2">
.....
</div>

 .background1 {
   width: 100%;
   background: radial-gradient(120% 800px at 50% -30px, red 75%, 
    transparent 75%)  no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

  .background2 {
   background-color: #202492;
   width: 100%;
   background: radial-gradient(120% 800px at 50% -30px,blue 75%, 
   transparent 75%) no-repeat;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   margin-top: -50px;
   }
```

But I am getting this
[image]

> Blockquote

Comment: You don't curve the divs, you create the effect by using a background-image. In your it might work with a radial-gradient. You can also use a SVG or a png/jpg... image

Comment: @cloned I have updated my question can you please check that?

Comment: I would scrap having a separate divs for each color. You can add more colors to the one background radial-gradient in a parent container.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```css
.btn1 {
    background: #190b0b;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em 2.5em;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px -1px #190b0b;
}
.background1 {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 6em 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 10em 10em;
    text-align: center;
}

.background2 {
    background-color: #202492;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 6em 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 10em 10em;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    top: -10em;
    color: #fff;
}

.background3 {
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 6em 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 10em 10em;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    top: -20em;
    color: #fff;
}

.text {
    margin-top: 6em;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 0 6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="background1">
  <button class="btn1">Button</button>
</div>

<div class="background2">
  <div class="text"> 
    <h2> Text1 </h2>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pellentesque, nibh sed tempus bibendum, lacus turpis dictum ipsum, nec consectetur diam nisi eget mauris.  </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="background3">
  <div class="text"> 
    <h2> Text2 </h2>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pellentesque, nibh sed tempus bibendum, lacus turpis dictum ipsum, nec consectetur diam nisi eget mauris.  </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just change in `border-radius` and `padding` values to have the perfect curve that you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use border-bottom-left-radius and border-bottom-lright-radius or border-radius: 0px 0px xxxpx xxpx;

```css
div {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 200px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: And how does this help to have a second div underneath with a continuous colour? Can you expand your answer?

Comment: You can keep 3 div, separated using position properties of css. And in case some portion of div is getting overlapped then use the z index css to bring it to front from other.